# PhantomJS is failed to find all elements on linux server

Tags: java, linux, maven, jenkins, phantomjs

I am running testcase. It is working fine on my localhost jenkins. Code is published at bitbucket.

Now I have setup everything on linux dedicated server of amazone. When I run test through jenkinsit is giving me error for method and says unable to find element.

How it is possible that code and everything is same but on localhost everything running perfect and on linux server it is unable to find element.

Stack Trace :

> {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class name
>   'log'","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"36","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:18633","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java
>   1.5)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"class name\",\"value\":\"log\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/751de200-2438-11e6-adf9-e13c80ddc389/element"}}
>   Command duration or timeout: 426 milliseconds For documentation on
>   this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.45.0', revision:
>   '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27
>   09:10:26' System info: host: 'ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX'', ip: 'XXX-XX-XX-XXX'',
>   os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '4.4.8-20.46.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_05' Driver info:
>   org.openqa.selenium.phantomjs.PhantomJSDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=false,
>   databaseEnabled=false, version=1.9.7, platform=LINUX,
>   browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={proxyType=direct},
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, driverVersion=1.1.0,
>   locationContextEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=false,
>   browserName=phantomjs, takesScreenshot=true, driverName=ghostdriver,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   751de200-2438-11e6-adf9-e13c80ddc389 *** Element info: {Using=class
>   name, value=log}
>
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebDriver.java:433)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:387)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:59)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:37)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.click(Unknown Source)  at
>   pages.LoginPage.SwitchtoLogin(LoginPage.java:124)  at
>   testcases.LoginTest.LoginBtnStatusCheck(LoginTest.java:79)  34 lines
>   not shown Caused by Screen shot has been taken Build info: version:
>   '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time:
>   '2015-02-27 09:10:26' System info: host: 'ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX', ip:
>   'XXX-XX-XX-XXX', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '4.4.8-20.46.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_05' Driver info:
>   driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
>
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:136)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByClassName(RemoteWebDriver.java:433)
>   at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByClassName.findElement(By.java:387)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:59)
>   at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:37)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.click(Unknown Source)  at
>   pages.LoginPage.SwitchtoLogin(LoginPage.java:124)  at
>   testcases.LoginTest.LoginBtnStatusCheck(LoginTest.java:79)  34 lines
>   not shown Caused by {"errorMessage":"Unable to find element with class
>   name
>   'log'","request":{"headers":{"Accept-Encoding":"gzip,deflate","Connection":"Keep-Alive","Content-Length":"36","Content-Type":"application/json;
>   charset=utf-8","Host":"localhost:18633","User-Agent":"Apache-HttpClient/4.3.6 (java
>   1.5)"},"httpVersion":"1.1","method":"POST","post":"{\"using\":\"class name\",\"value\":\"log\"}","url":"/element","urlParsed":{"anchor":"","query":"","file":"element","directory":"/","path":"/element","relative":"/element","port":"","host":"","password":"","user":"","userInfo":"","authority":"","protocol":"","source":"/element","queryKey":{},"chunks":["element"]},"urlOriginal":"/session/751de200-2438-11e6-adf9-e13c80ddc389/element"}}
>   For documentation on this error, please visit:
>   http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html Build info:
>   version: '2.45.0', revision:
>   '5017cb8e7ca8e37638dc3091b2440b90a1d8686f', time: '2015-02-27
>   09:10:26' System info: host: 'ip-XXX-XX-XX-XXX', ip: 'XXX-XX-XX-XXX',
>   os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '4.4.8-20.46.amzn1.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_05' Driver info:
>   driver.version: unknown
>
> 1 lines not shown

Comment: Different jenkins versions?  Different jenkins plugins installed?  Check that you have installed everything you need.

Comment: Yes jenkins versions are diff. That can create issue?